# Is there a way to see how much memory my app will take up while it's in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, ios-simulator

I'm designing an iPhone application and writing a paper on it.  I was wondering how I can see how much virtual/real memory my application will take in the iPhone.  I am currently running it in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be done accurately. You can get consistently good values for *most* of the APIs you use using the Allocations instrument, but there are differences in execution environments which make *exact* figures impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you want to Profile you app. In Xcode, hold down the "Run" button and select Profile. A window should pop up asking you to select an Instrument to profile your app with. For memory usage, you can analyze your apps using either Allocations or Leaks. I would do some googling for instructions on how to use these two instruments.